# Matlab axes gui

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I generate a graph inside a function and I want to call that graph inside my gui but I don't get how can I do it.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
function [h1,h2] = namefuction(input)
%stuff
h1 = plot(x1,y1);
h2 = plot(x2,y2)
```

Then I call this function inside my `.fig` file and I get in the workspace a `line` variable for my two plots, then I try to plot them into two separate axes but I fail in this.

For now I'm doing something in order to have the plot code inside the `.fig` file and before i call `plot(x,y)` I use `axes(handles.axes1);` and it works, but I don't like this solution.

Does exist a solution for this?

Comment: you can use `set(gcf,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes1)` to set the current axes of figure and then use `plot(x,y)` to plot the graph

Comment: Do you mean inside the function that generates the plot? I already tried this way but it gives me this error `Undefined variable "handles" or class "handles.axes1".` because that function has no handles inside.